# upload file on drive d:// php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload files from apps running on the local computer to another drive outside the drive where my application's root folder. Here I include the folder structure:

> - root app:
>   C: // Program files / zend / apache / htdocs / myWeb
>
> This is the file destination path I want to upload:
> D: // attached file / web / file.jpg

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like

```
 copy('C:/Program files/zend/apache/htdocs/myWeb', 'D:/attached file/web/file.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifies the file with drive path in move_uploaded_file() method

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "D:/somefolder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```