# PHP upload/read files on separate drive

Tags: php, upload, drive

I need to be able to upload/view files on a separate drive.

Right now, my site is in the htdocs folder on the C: drive.  We have been allocated space on the D: drive to upload and view files.

Using the code below, I can use scandir to view what is located in htdocs folder:

```
<?php
 $dir    = '../../htdocs/';
 $files1 = scandir($dir);
 $files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

 print_r($files1);
 print_r($files2);
?>
```

But I need to traverse back a few more to be able to get to the D: drive.  I am not sure if this is even possible.

Using the above code, when I attempt to traverse to the D: drive, the path would look something like this:

```
$dir    = '../../../D:/uploadFiles/';
```

I am not sure if that is the correct format when going back and viewing something in the D: drive.  I guess if it was, I would be seeing something on the screen, which I am not.

Upon conducting my research online, the closest thing that I could find was this post:

[upload file on drive d:// php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118695/upload-file-on-drive-d-php)

But I need to be able to first read the files in the folder on the D: drive.

Is what I am trying to do possible using PHP? If it is, how can I fix my path so that I can see the files in the uploadFiles folder on the D: drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All [Directory Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php).

Simple as:

```
scandir('C:/some/path/uploadFiles');
scandir('D:/some/path/www/htdocs');
```

Or whatever... Write out the **full paths**. Don't even do that `../../` stuff. Relative paths / absolute paths. I think you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: So, I am trying to echo the following path, as follows:   echo scandir('D:/uploadFiles');  but nothing is showing on screen.  Thoughts?

Comment: Well "nothing"... would mean what? You are echoing an empty string or that you are getting an error...

Comment: my apologies.  I am not getting any errors.  The screen is blank, whereas I should at least be able to see an array with a list of directories.

Comment: Well what happens if you go to the command prompt and type `dir D:/uploadFiles`? Don't have a windows instance handy at the moment but cAsE probably doesn't matter..

Comment: And per your response about scandir and an error.. `Returns an array of filenames on success, or FALSE on failure. If directory is not a directory, then boolean FALSE is returned, and an error of level E_WARNING is generated. `

Comment: Using the command prompt, upon navigating to the D: drive and looking into the uploadFiles folder, I see the following:  Volume in drive D is Data, Volume Serial Number is blahblahblah.  Then I am seeing a bunch of dates, which appear to be the creation dates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174188/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-john-beasley).

Comment: Turned out a warning was being issued, once found that lead us to `open_basedir` being the culprit. @JohnBeasley I should just add that on my dedicated front end servers I usually just turn that off entirely.