# PHP open_basedir restriction: (file) is not within the allowed path

Tags: php, drive, nas, scandir, open-basedir

Previously, I had attempted to upload and view files from another drive, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142542/php-upload-read-files-on-separate-drive).

The web files were on the htdocs folder on the C: drive, but I needed to be able to save to a folder on the D: drive.  I was successful completing this task.

By updating the open_basedir portion in the php.ini file, I simply added the additional extension like this:

```
open_basedir = 'C:\inetPub;D:\CargoDocsPDFs;'
```

Then, I can use PHP's scandir to make sure I can see the folders in the D: drive, as follows:

```
<?php
$files1 =  scandir('D:/CargoDocsPDFs');
var_dump($files1);
?>
```

Which gives me the following:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(9) "000000000" [3]=> string(10) "0000000000" [4]=> string(10) "0001782136" [5]=> string(10) "0004670615" }
```

Here is where my new problem begins...

We've been given a new drive to upload and view files from.  It's a network drive allocated with more space the previous D: drive.

The new network drive has been labeled as the S: drive.  So I figure I could simply update the php.ini file again:

```
open_basedir = 'C:\inetPub;S:\CargoDocsPDFs'
```

Then I run the same PHP scandir function (with error reporting on):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//$files1 =  scandir('D:/CargoDocsPDFs');
$files2 =  scandir('S:/CargoDocsPDFs');

//var_dump($files1);
var_dump($files2);
?>
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
Warning: scandir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(S:/CargoDocsPDFs) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\inetPub;S:\CargoDocsPDFs) in C:\inetpub\mylocation\CargoReadiness\test.php on line 14

Warning: scandir(S:/CargoDocsPDFs): failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in C:\inetpub\mylocation\CargoReadiness\test.php on line 14

Warning: scandir(): (errno 1): Operation not permitted in C:\inetpub\mylocation\CargoReadiness\test.php on line 14

bool(false)
```

Why am I getting this new found error, and how do I fix it?

### Edit

Here are the how the privileges are set in the 2 drives below.  The properties on the left is the drive I am trying to connect to, which is the S: drive, and a network drive.  The properties on the right is the D: drive, and is the drive that I can successfully upload and view the PDFs.

[image]

If you'll notice the S: drive, the privileges for Everyone are all checked except for Special Permissions (Full Control is also unchecked, but you cannot see it in the pic).  Whereas the D: drive, the only privileges checked is Special Permissions.

I am not sure if this has anything to do with my error.

### Edit 2

It has been revealed to me that the device I have been trying to connect to is a NAS device.  I am not sure what that means, nor do I know if the current issue at hand is related to why I cannot connect to the device.

Comment: Your user, which executes the PHP code is probably not having the privilege to access the new drive.

Comment: have You tried with: `$files2 =  scandir('S:\CargoDocsPDFs');` ? I mean maybe it's checking forward and backslashes for network drive?  or try with glob:   `$files2 =  glob('S:\CargoDocsPDFs\*');`

Comment: @LajosArpad - Any thoughts on how I can adjust the privileges?

Comment: @num8er - When I use glob, the output is: array(0) { }.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @num8er - I made a couple of updates.  I am hoping you would take a look.

Comment: Very dumb idea: You added "S:\CargoDocsPDFs" to the open_basedir. But PHP complains that it cannot open "S:/CargoDocsPDFs". See the difference? Try adding the folder with a slash instead of a backslash to the open_basedir and try if it works... Maybe thats some weird quirk because its a network drive? I'm not sure but its worth a shot...